# ciscoaxl api python errors

Tags: python, cisco-axl, cucm

I am starting out working on looking into using Python for some Cisco CUCM automation. I found the plugin ciscoaxl [here](https://pypi.org/project/ciscoaxl/), I installed it and programed the following script:

```
from ciscoaxl import axl
cucm = "10.10.20.1"
username = "axlusr"
password = "password1"
version = "12.5"
ucm = axl(username, password, cucm, version)
for phone in ucm.get_phones():
    print(phone.name)
```

I am connected to Cisco's DevNET Sandbox and all the login and configuration for the AXL user appear to be correct, however I get the following output when I attempt to run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\axl-test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for phone in ucm.get_phones():
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ciscoaxl\axl.py", line 1877, in get_phones
    for each in inner(skip):
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ciscoaxl\axl.py", line 1869, in inner
    res = self.client.listPhone(
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 40, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 130, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 195, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "%home%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 283, in process_error
    raise Fault(
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Unknown fault occured
```

I have run it on Windows10 in an IDLE enviornment, from the Linux-Subsystem (Ubuntu 20.04) via python and ipython3.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research this is a know issue with CUCM 12.5. It should be fixed in CU1 see here: https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/989

Answer (score 0):

I still receive this error on 12.5.1.12900-115, but I receive it when I don't have the appropriate permissions. Fixing user permissions for AXL access resolves it.